# Multiple image selection from gallery

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to select multiple images at once from gallery?
I tried using the Display's `openGallery` method but that seems to support only one image selection at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API at this time, only single selection is available.